# Can't reach my prometheus and grafana deployed in docker on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, grafana, prometheus, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to monitor my app with Prometheus and Grafana, running in Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but have issues with deploying it correctly.

Here is my `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "prometheus-conf",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/prometheus"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "prometheus-app",
      "image": "prom/prometheus",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 9090,
          "containerPort": 9090
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "prometheus-conf",
          "containerPath": "/opt/prometheus"
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "--config.file=/opt/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "grafana",
      "image": "grafana/grafana",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 256,
      "links": [
        "prometheus-app"
       ],
       "portMappings": [
         {
           "hostPort": 3000,
           "containerPort": 3000
         }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Here is my `prometheus.yml` in `prometheus` folder:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
rule_files:
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'jParser'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['jParser.fpemryt2er.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

When I run it locally with `eb local run` in `eb cli`, everything works fine, I can access prometheus on `localhost:9090` and grafana on `localhost:3000`.

When I deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with `eb deploy`, the process ends successfully and I can see the instance in my Dashboard, but in a minute status `OK` switches to `Severe` with message `Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.` and `100.0 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx (10 minutes ago)`:

[image]

But when I look on this instance in EC2 management console, it shows, that instance is running without any problems:

[image]

In my Task definitions console I also can see Prometheus and Grafana running without any problems:

[image]

But anyway, I can't reach neither prometheus nor grafana by typing provided by EB url + :port, e.g.: `jd-env.8myne2inmq.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:9090`. I also tried to use public DNS and IP, shown in EC2 console, but it doesn't work too.

In my loadbalancer i opened ports 9090 and 3000:

[image]

Please, help me get these apps working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. After opening ports `9090` and `3000` in Loadbalancer, it is also necessary to switch EC2 security groups in `Configurations/Instances/`. After that new load balancing config with these ports open becomes available.

One more problem was that Elastic beanstalk health monitoring system tries to check for port `80`, but in my case there nothing there, so health status was always red. In `Configurations/Monitoring` I changed this to endpoint `HTTP:9090/graph` - now it visits Prometheus main page and health is green.